# Cheerio Get Image Src

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

im try to image for a table and push that link in to array. when i run the code `img` get an undefined.
how i can fix this problem.

```
$("body > form > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr").each((index, element) => {
                if (index === 0) return true;

                const tds = $(element).find("td");

                const img = $(tds[0]).attr('src'); // undefined
                const flight = $(tds[1]).text(); //working
                const origin = $(tds[2]).text(); //working
                const time = $(tds[3]).text(); //working
                const estimted = $(tds[4]).text(); //working
                const status = $(tds[5]).text(); //working

                console.log(img);

                const tableRow = {
                    flight,
                    origin,
                    time,
                    estimted,
                    status
                };
            });
```

Comment: Try $(tds[0]).find('img').attr('src') instead of $(tds[0]).attr('src')

Comment: You should provide us with the html code

Answer (score 0):

`$(tds[0]).attr('src')` will be undefined because td's aren't images.

Maybe you wanted: `$(tds[0]).find('img').attr('src')`